# Why is this True? I find it False

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Mostly I believe in math. However I have trouble in my economic textbook (which really should be right).

I have the following equation:

$ u(c,d)=\left(ac^{\frac{1-\gamma}{\theta}}+b d^{\frac{1-\gamma}{\theta}}\right)^{\frac{\theta}{1-\gamma}}$

where $\theta=(1-\gamma)/(1-1/\psi)$, $a\in (0,1)$,$b\in (0,1)$, $c>0$, $d>0$, $\gamma>0$, and $\psi>0)$.

So now my True or False question follows: Is it true or false that the derivative wrt. $c$ is:
$ u_c(c,d)=ac^{\frac{1-\gamma}{\theta}-1}\left(ac^{\frac{1-\gamma}{\theta}}+b d^{\frac{1-\gamma}{\theta}}\right)^{\frac{\theta}{1-\gamma}-1}=ac^{-1/\psi}u(c,d)^{1/\psi}$

Can some tell me why this is true ? I would write it as

$ u_c(c,d)=ac^{\frac{1-\gamma}{\theta}-1}\left(ac^{\frac{1-\gamma}{\theta}}+b d^{\frac{1-\gamma}{\theta}}\right)^{\frac{\theta}{1-\gamma}-1}=ac^{-1/\psi}u(c,d)^{-1}$

Hope to hear from someone,
Thanks in advance